# How can I get email address of Yahoo Answer users?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, yahoo-api

I am using Yahoo Answers API to build a c# desktop application which goes to Yahoo Answers and search for any keyword you enter and it brings the list of questions and their users. I need to get Email Address of those users so that I can send message to them.

Anyone tried it ? It is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the [Yahoo API](http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/) doesn't return this information. This is most probably to prevent people sending unsolicited email to their users.

Answer (score -4):

You should use [Yahoo Answers API](http://kentbrewster.com/yahoo-answers-api/) to do it